# PRIMARY KEY ПО 2 полям

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с столбцами: product_id, date, price

---

Как сделать проверку на уникальность по полям date, price ? Что бы при вставке не повторялась запись

> - если 05.12.2019 и 100 уже существует- не вставлять запись.
> - если 05.12.2019 и 101 не существует- вставлять запись.

Спасибо.

Comment: и в чем проблема-то?

Comment: Да так и сделать - созданием первичного или уникального индекса по этим двум полям (не два индекса по отдельному полю каждый!).

Comment: *уникальность по полям date, price* Что, два продукта в один день не могут иметь одинаковую цену? странно, аднака...

Comment: @Akina, данная таблица нужна для графика изменения цен, так как update для данной таблицы может выполнятся 3 раза в день, не хочу что бы повторялась дата с одной и той же ценой

Comment: *не хочу что бы повторялась дата с одной и той же ценой* Для ОДНОГО И ТОГО ЖЕ ПРОДУКТА? Или вообще - вечером апельсины не могут стоить столько, сколько утром стоили яблоки?

Comment: @Akina согласен, спасибо за направление

Comment: Охотно верю, что согласен... но нам-то ясность внести? желательно путём редактирования текста вопроса.

Comment: @Akina буду благодарен за внесение ясности, я так понимаю мне нужно делать по всем 3 полям, возможно есть другие идеи ?

Comment: *я так понимаю мне нужно делать по всем 3 полям, возможно есть другие идеи?* Все другие идеи заведомо хуже. Ну разве что у вас там дисковое пространство жутко дорогое - тогда смотрите [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1054642/229437) товарища [becouse](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/346909/becouse) - триггер, правда, с существенными ошибками, но сам подход имеет право на существование.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`date`, `price`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я поставил не правильно вопрос, но нашел идеальное решение в виде

```sql
INSERT INTO price_history (product_id, date, price) 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'product_id', 'date', 'price') AS tmp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT price_history WHERE product_id = '1' AND date = '2019-12-05' AND price = '415') 
LIMIT 1;
```

Таким образом если планировщик будет обновлять сегодня базу и повторится значение, он пропустит и не будет дублировать значение.
Спасибо всем.

Answer (score -2):

Например вот так

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS check_info;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER check_info BEFORE INSERT myTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE date = NEW.date and price=NEW.price) THEN
    INSERT INTO myTable (date,price)
    VALUES (NEW.myTable.date,NEW.myTable.price);
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Решать триггером задачу, которая легко решается без него? не учите детей плохому...

Comment: @Akina Насколько было понятно из условия нужно было именно не заносить дубликаты по определенным полям. В общем случае использовать для этого первичный индекс тоже не комильфо.

Comment: Первичный - да (хотя я нигде явных запретов на натуральные ПК не видел). А вот просто уникальный индекс - сам бог велел... Но не триггером же...